# How to extract full path from the excel hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have a worksheet where i have maintained a column which contains the hyperlink to other worksheets.

```
Set rngx = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1:C10000").Find("Power Plant 1", lookat:=xlPart)

BR2 = rngx.Hyperlinks(1).Address
```

Here in BR2 previously i used to get the particular hyperlink path as 
"Projects\Power Plant\Power Plant EPC 1.xlsm"

Later i went into info->properties and changed the Hyperlink base to C:\ , 
After mentioning the hyperlink base now i am getting the hyperlink path as   "Users\inkapb\AppData\Local\Temp\EPC AutoTool\Projects\Power Plant\Power Plant EPC 1.xlsm"

My question is I need the path from C: drive like "C:\Users\inkapb\AppData\Local\Temp\EPC AutoTool\Projects\Power Plant\Power Plant EPC 1.xlsm" is it possible to achieve this without appending C:\ in the code.

Comment: Does the user **inkapb** change? If another user is using the workbook, does the link still reference the --inkapb-- user's profile folders?

Comment: inkapb User will change, if any other is using the workbook then their User name will get replaced as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the hyperlink address using the **%LOCALAPPDATA%** environment variable.

```
'as a formula
=HYPERLINK("%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp\EPC AutoTool\Projects\Power Plant\Power Plant EPC 1.xlsm", "Power Plant 1")

'as VBA
rngx.Hyperlinks(1).Address = Environ("LOCALAPPDATA") & _
  "\Temp\EPC AutoTool\Projects\Power Plant\Power Plant EPC 1.xlsm"
'or,
rngx.Hyperlinks(1).Address = "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp\EPC AutoTool\Projects\Power Plant\Power Plant EPC 1.xlsm"
```

Retrieving the .Address from the [Hyperlinks object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839966.aspx) or the [HYPERLINK function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HYPERLINK-function-333C7CE6-C5AE-4164-9C47-7DE9B76F577F) should retrieve the correct full path and filename.

```
BR2 = rngx.Hyperlinks(1).Address
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the Full path.
Instead of hyperlink base as "C:\" i changed it to "x", it worked like a charm.